# PDO not inserting my JSON data

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I was trying to import my JSON data into my databse. But it does not seem to work. It does not give me any errors at all. Here is my code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$jsondata = file_get_contents('https://hugo.events/genre/pop/next/200/100');
$data     = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$uname     = 'a1070rik';
$upass     = '';
$dbh       = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=wtd', $uname, $upass);
$statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pop(id, event_name, event_date, event_lang_long, event_genres, event_desc, event_logo, event_header_pic)
    VALUES('', :name, :date, :lang_long, :genres, :desc, :logo, :header_pic)");
    $id = $data[1]['hits']['hits'][1]['_id'];
foreach ($data[1]['hits']['hits'] as $row) {
    $statement->execute(array(
        "name" => $row['fields']['name'][0],
        "date" => $row['fields']['start'][0],
        "lang_long" => "test",
        "genres" => $row['fields']['genres'][0],
        "desc" => $row['fields']['description'][0],
        "logo" => $row['fields']['logo'][0],
        "header_pic" => $row['fields']['header'][0]
    ));
}
```

The JSON data:
https://ghostbin.com/paste/evjgk

I hope someone can help me. Tried to figure this out all day.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove id from column list and `''` from value list

Comment: @Jens Nothing happening. Still the samew

Comment: @randy When I output it in an array it all works